# Cannot Navigate from Push Notification to Chosen Screen

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-push-notification

When the user clicks or presses the notification I want to have a particular screen open. I have been gone through various github issues and stack overflow questions and answers however there does not seem to be one answer or chosen way to go about this.

Originally I used a PushController class to handle the onNotification function however not I have moved the configure and onNotification functions to the component did mount in my component where the local notification is being created.

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('RouteName');
```

Does not work. It says that `this.props.navigation` or `this.props.navigation.navigate` are undefined.

```
PushNotification.
            onNotification(notification) {
                console.log('onNotification')
                console.log( notification );
this.props.navigation.navigate('RegisterRoute');
            },

        });
```

What is the correct way to go about routing or navigating from notification to chosen screen. I cannot find a direct answer in the react-native-push-notification issues and documentation.

Edit:
This code can be found within the class where I call/make the local notification. 
The notification is triggered and called, and when the notification is clicked or onNotification I would like to navigate or route to another screenn.

Inside the component did mount.

```
PushNotification.configure({

            onNotification(notification) {
                console.log('onNotification')
                console.log( notification );
this.props.navigation.navigate('ChosenScreen');
            },


        });
```

The function that calls and creates a local notification

```
function sendNotification(title, pushMessage){
        PushNotification.localNotification({
        message: pushMessage, 
        title: title,
        userInteraction: true,
        alertAction: 'default',// (optional) default: view

       autoCancel: true, 
       largeIcon: "logo", 
       smallIcon: "logo",
       vibrate: true, 
       vibration: 300,

       alertAction: 'default',
       userInfo: 'default'

      });

}
```

Comment: can you add more code, it is quite unclear that what is happening in your code.

Comment: Alright. I will add it right now.

Comment: Your question is about react-navigation and NOT react-native-navigation

Comment: How did you made it work @Carrie? I'm getting the notification but when I click on it I dont get any console in my onNotification method. Been stuck for hours.

Comment: Hey @3iL I have posted the solution to my problem. I hope it helps!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is how I solved my problem.

I found a guide (I can't find the link) on how to create a navigation service which helped fix the issue of props being undefined. I imported this service and it is what I use to navigate.

**Where my notification is declared and used**

```
import NavigationService from './NavigationService.js';

compnentDidMount(){
  PushNotification.configure({
    onNotification(notification){
    console.log('onNotification')
    console.log(notification );
      NavigationService.navigate('Route', {Params: param});


  },
  });

}
```

**The navigation service class**

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

let _navigator;

function setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef) {
  _navigator = navigatorRef;
}

function navigate(routeName, params) {
  _navigator.dispatch(
    NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName,
      params,
    })
  );
}

export default {
  navigate,
  setTopLevelNavigator,
};
```

Comment: Here is that link:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html

Comment: You never set your top level navigator'

Answer (score 0):

`this.props.navigation was undefined` means that your component has no **navigation** prop. You have to use [withNavigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation.html) which is a higher order component.

Comment: hey can you check this Q please, @AungMyatHein
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57171787/navigate-to-screen-after-opening-a-notification

Answer (score 0):

Probably Your `onOpened` function does not have the right scope because it is being called within `addEventListener` function so you have to bind `this`.

Ex: (good)

```
 OneSignal.addEventListener('opened', this.onOpened.bind(this));
```

(wrong) - no navigation access

```
 OneSignal.addEventListener('received', this.onReceived);
```

Comment: hey can you check this Q please, @StephenRauch

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57171787/navigate-to-screen-after-opening-a-notification